# Get contacts off sim card phone with broken screen

Tags: sim-card

Need some help. Finally switching to smartphone after the screen broke on my flip phone. All my contacts are on the SIM card, but I can’t see anything on the screen. How can I access that information? Thanks.

Comment: You could place the SIM in a non-broken phone first, and copy the contacts, and then restore them to your new phone. Also at some shops they can cut SIM-Cards for you, if your don't want to do it yourself :)

Comment: Use the Contacts app's Import -> From SIM Card option

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are now moving to a smartphone from the flip phone (presumably Android, as this exchange is for Android), you would need a new, smaller SIM card from your provider or you would have to manually cut the SIM to the right size, which I wouldn't advise. There's a good likelihood of breaking it. However, if you put the card you have now in another device with the same size SIM, you can manually copy over the contacts.

If you don't have another phone to do this with and don't want to cut the current SIM, you can probably bring the SIM to a store of your cellular provider and they will assist you.

If you are able to fit the old SIM into the phone, which is incredibly unlikely, open the default contact app. In the top right corner, there are 3 vertical dots. A drop down menu will open and one of the options will be import/export contacts. In the next menu, there will be an option that says Import from SIM.

Comment: Thanks, I was told the new Android I bought is built on a "CDMA platform" and therefore there is no place to put the SIM card as I thought there would be when I purchased it. Been trying to track some one down with a working SIM based phone but no luck yet.

Comment: Odd. I've never heard of phones besides iphones doing that, and that only started last week.

Comment: Ethan, could you add some info as to how to copy the contacts or import them from the SIM card in Android so they show up on the new device, just in case it might have a SIM?

Comment: @TamoghnaChowdhury, yes, one minute.

Comment: @TamoghnaChowdhury in the default contacts app, there is an option to import contacts from the SIM card.

Comment: Ethan, I meant add it in your answer. Not as a comment. I know this option exists, otherwise I wouldn't have commented that to the OP in the question. Your answers should be as complete as possible as we try to help  as many people as possible with one answer.